# Using Admin site layout and front site layout angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am working on application which includes front site layout and admin site layout both of them have different JS and CSS files. I want to keep them a part not to conflict with each other. Here is my index.html page code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Couaff</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://explorercanvas.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/excanvas.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- **Favicon** -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!-- **CSS - stylesheets** -->
    <link id="default-css" href="assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="assets/css/shortcode.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- **Additional - stylesheets** -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link href="assets/css/animations.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link id="skin-css" href="assets/skins/red/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/meanmenu.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/pace-theme-loading-bar.css">

    <!-- **Font Awesome** -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- **Google - Fonts** -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="assets/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>


  <!-- **jQuery** -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.sticky.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.inview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jsplugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.meanmenu.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Currently I have kept only front site layout JS and CSS files. Here is the architecture and site layout component. For reference see below image.

[Angular-Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD50Q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you want to have 2 code bases for 2 different entries in a single Angular project. If so you can do these steps

### 1. Create a new project for your admin entry

```
ng g application admin --routing=true
```

Change `admin` to any name you wanted.

By doing this a new directory `projects/admin` will be created under your base directory (`couaff-angular-web`)

### 2. Configure outputPath

Assuming you want to have your admin entry under `https://{host}/admin/` then you will need to either configure your host to target to `dist/admin` directory

Or you can open `angular.json`.Then locate `projects.admin.architect.build.options.outputPath` and change it to whatever path you prefered

```
"outputPath": "../admin",
```

Where `admin` is the name of of the path of your choice (pick anything you like)

### 3. Configure your base path in `index.html`

*(NOTE: this is depends on your host configuration like if you have dedicated host configured for admin page then this step is not required)*

Open `index.html` for admin project, locate `<base>` tag. You will need to update it to something like this

```
<!-- NOTE the original value is "/" - which will cause admin project to fetch assets in your base project -->
<base href="/admin/">
```

### 4. Run your application like you normally do

```
ng serve|build 
# or 
ng serve|build --project=admin
```

Depend on what you wanted you can either

- Run `ng serve|build` without any param. Your default (base) project will be runing
- Run `ng serve|build` with `--project=admin` param. Your child project will be running

Reference: [ng-cli doc](https://angular.io/cli/generate#application)

---

***EDIT***: I make a mistake in step 4. Added param `--project=admin` for the command lines - and fixed the answer

Comment: Can please guide me how to add component through angular cli in admin and please what about the routing how to manage that too.

Comment: @MuhammadKamran when you run any `ng generate` command - add param `--project=admin` . By this component,service... all will be created in your admin project (you can also import component from parent project too). For routing just configure it like you normally do - also it will be easier to use use hash `#` routing.